# Java: Console class

Tags: java, input, console, passwords, overwrite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why is char[] preferred over string for passwords?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords)

Reading the java documentation, i found this statement about [Console](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Console.html) class

> First, it suppresses echoing, so the password is not visible on the user's screen. Second, readPassword returns a character array, not a String, so the password can be overwritten, removing it from memory as soon as it is no longer needed.

Why a character array can be overwritten and a String not?
Or maybe a character array can be overwritted in a more simple way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8881291/why-is-char-preferred-over-string-for-passwords

Comment: That is just for information. That thread has good description about why char array preferred over String. Because it is just FYI, I pasted as comment.

Answer (score 1):

A `String` could be kept in something called a `String pool` by the JVM to manage memory usage for `String`s more efficiently. A side effect of this however, is that it may be kept in memory even after you overwrite the reference with a new `String`.
A character array however can be directly overwritten, and is therefore safer in this respect.

Answer (score -1):

From the Sun Certified Java Programmer for Java 6 Study Guide:

> the readPassword method doesn't return a string: it returns a character array. Here's the reason for this: Once you've got the password, you can verify it and then absolutely remove it from memory. If a string was returned, it could exist in a pool somewhere in memory and perhaps some nefarious hacker could find it.